# load php function on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to call a php function if an ajax request is successful.

Basic setup code:

```
wp_register_script( 'theme-follow-me-ajax', ... );   

    wp_localize_script('theme-follow-me-ajax', 'ajax_setting', array(
        'ajax_url'              => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'ajax_follow_error'     => $this->km_follow_me_error(),
        ....
    ));

    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-follow-me-ajax' );
```

Content to display the error, which should be customizable

```
 public function km_follow_me_error() {

    $content = esc_html__( 'An error happened. We\'re unable to complete your request.', 'theme' );

    echo apply_filters( 'theme_hook_follow_me_error_message', $content );

}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax( {
        url : ajax_setting.ajax_url,
        type : 'post', 
        data: {  
            action                      : 'km_ajax_follow_me',
            security                    : ajax_setting.ajax_nonce,
            ... 
        },  
        success: function( data ) {         
            $('.km-follow-me').html( ajax_setting.ajax_follow_success ).hide().fadeIn( 'slow' );            
            //console.log( ajax_setting.ajax_follow_success );
        },  
    } )
```

WP `wp_ajax_` function

```
public function addon_ajax_follow_me() {

        check_ajax_referer( 'km-ajax-create-nonce', 'security' );   

        ... update user meta ...

        wp_die();   

    }

    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_km_ajax_follow_me', $plugin_public, 'addon_ajax_follow_me' );
```

In console I get the `null` message, so it's not grabbing the `km_follow_me_error` function.

Is there a better way?

Comment: your first ajax call effectively "calls a PHP function". This is the correct way to do so, there's no way to directly do it from script because PHP runs on the server and JS runs on the client, and at different times in the page lifecyle as well. So to call another PHP function, you need to repeat the same pattern, i.e. another ajax call to a different URL which will run some PHP to call the function you need, and return the results to the browser.

Comment: Could you create an example? Or know of a tutorial that explain this in more detail? Most tutorials about wp ajax doesn't cover this subject (ajax within ajax).

Comment: there's nothing to it. In the success function of the first ajax call, make another ajax call using the same syntax. Sorry I would have thought it was obvious, you already know how to make an ajax call. BTW nothing about this is specific to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it incorrectly. A PHP function cannot be called/accessed from Javascript the way you're trying to do. You have two options to call that function on your AJAX success.

1. Create/register another AJAX function in WordPress, maybe named as `ajax_follow_success` and call it in success of the previous AJAX call.
2. Identify in your first function WordPress AJAX function i.e. `addon_ajax_follow_me` whether it's a success or failure and call the next function there.

Comment: How to check if it's success or failure inside the php function? Could you create an example?

Comment: @kiarashi That totally depends on your logic. What do you call that AJAX function for? Is that executed perfectly and you got the expected result/value? If yes, then it's a success otherwise not.